# Load spinner while loading

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I want to load a spinner when my account page is loading, it is taking a bit time to load "myaccount" page so i want to load a spinner using spinner atmosphere package.

Here is my code,where do i need to add {> spinner} to load the spinner

```
this.route('myaccount', {path:'/myaccount/',
            fastRender: true
    });
```

for myaccount,it need to contact 3rd party api to load some data to page.

Suggest me which is the best place to load spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [NProgress](https://atmospherejs.com/package/nprogress) preloader then you can achieve it like that:

```
this.route('myaccount', {
    path:'/myaccount/',

    action:function(){
        self = this;
        self.render('header', {to:'header'});
        NProgress.start();
        // load external data and onComplete (callback) it renders template and stops preloader
        MyAccount.loadData(function(){
            self.render(self.template);
            NProgress.done();
        })
    }
  });
```

## Update :

#### Standard solution for using Spinner with Meteor subscription mechanism is using waitOn function:

```
<template name="loadingTemplate">
  {{>spinner}}
</template>


<template name="layout">
    <nav>
      {{> yield region='header'}}
    </nav>
    {{> yield}}
    <footer>
      {{> yield region='footer'}}
    </footer>
</template>

Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loadingTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutTemplate',
  yieldTemplates: { 
    'header': { to: 'header' },
    'footer': { to: 'footer' }
  }
});

// 
this.route('myaccount', {
    path: '/myaccount',
    template:'myaccountTemplate',
    layoutTemplate: 'layoutTemplate',
    data: function() { 
        ...
    },
    waitOn: function () {  
      return Meteor.subscribe('...');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Is it automatically take this `loadingTemplate` or we need to give this in each template

Comment: If you define loadingTemplate in Router.configure then it is global and used by all routes if not overwrite by route itself.

Answer (score 0):

Iron-router-progress is great!

https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress

with this option, it's top

> Router.configure
>       progressDelay : 100